# how to select nested documents in mongodb?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Lets say I have a nested documents with this stucture:

```
{
    "_id": "a125",
    "Language": null,
    "Name": "Some name",
    "Related": [{
        "_id": "b125",
        "Status": 0,
    }, {
        "_id": "b126",
        "Status": 1,
    }]
}
```

is it possible using c# drivers to select "Related" model where id is b126 and at the same time to get parent document id (a125)?

As I imagine outcome should look like this:

```
{
  "_id": "a125",
  "Related": {
     "_id": "b126",
     "Status": 1,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use dot notation with the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_) projection operator to find the matching document and only include the matching `Related` element.

In the shell:

```js
db.test.findOne({'Related._id': 'b125'}, {'Related.$': 1})
```

To do this in C#:

```cs
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Related._id", "b125");
var projection = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("Related.$");
var result = await collection.Find(filter).Project(projection).FirstAsync();
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use [dot notation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.mongodb.org%2Fmanual%2Fcore%2Fdocument&ei=GLdZVc7MCqHMyAPSm4GABw&usg=AFQjCNEXCYcxZ9KxLPYgWA_oWORKJ_EJ9g&sig2=JS2aJ2Gj6B6rUSFCj4ng3w&bvm=bv.93564037,d.bGQ) for your purpose. Your query will look like this:

```
{"Related._id": "b126"}
```

This will bring you all the documents, with all the fields including your parent `_id`, where there is a document element in the `Related` array, which has a field `_id` with value `"b126"`